# How to split words in different divisions

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

```
$name = the Stack Overflow

<div class="greyWord"> {{ $name }} </div>
<div class="blackWord"> </div>
```

I want the first word '**the**' in division with class name **greyWord** and remaining words '**Stack Overflow**' in division class **blackWord**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this will work for you

```
$name="the Stack Overflow";
$arr=explode(" ",$name,2);

<div class="greyWord">{{$arr[0]}}</div>
<div class="blackWord"> {{ $arr[1]}}</div>
```